# create-react-app can't be loaded through nodejs express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Project structure:

```
- client (react)
  - build
  - public
  - src
  - package.json
  - ..
- server (nodejs)
  - index.js
  - package.json
  - ..
```

I have a react app, just a simple one, almost nothing changed from the create-react-app default, and I have edited the package.json-file like this:

```
...
"homepage": "http://localhost:5000",
...
```

I have a nodeJS-server running a port 5000, just a simple one. Code:

```
"use strict";
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');*

app.use('*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('server listening'));
```

When visiting http://localhost:5000 in the browser, I would expect the app would show up. The title of the app shows up and when I inspect the source code, I see the content of the index.html-file, but I get these errors:
[image]

I haven't changed a thing in the build-folder. I just ran `npm run build` and then started my server with `nodemon index.js`.

I guess it has something to do with the nodejs server, because when I run `npm start` in my client folder, and I visit http://localhost:3000 in the browser, I can see my app is working.

**Edit:**

My /build/index.html-file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./logo.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" /><link rel="manifest"
      href="./manifest.json" />
    <title>My app</title>
    <link href="./static/css/main.82f10d06.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      Je
      moet JavaScript aan hebben staan in je browser om deze website te kunnen
      gebruiken.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./static/js/runtime-main.118ea286.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/2.efca8ee1.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.fcf604e0.chunk.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Changing the include urls from `./static/...` to `static/...` or to `/static/...` gives the same results.

**NPM: serve:**

When i use 'npm-serve' it works when I change the urls to `static/...`. Urls like `./static/...` or `/static/...`dont work with serve.

**Edit 2: package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Another update:**

So I created a new react app with `create-react-app`. I did **exactly** the following steps:

```
$ npx create-react-app testapp
$ cd testapp
$ npm install
$ npm run build
$ cd build
$ serve
```

I now see the html content, but it's not styled and I still get errors (see below).

[image]

**I didn't change anything in the react-app or in package.json.**

Comment: Could you share package.json content?

Comment: Sure! I've added it to my question!

Comment: I can't really remember; I has a similar issue in the past, try and remove homepage, build and deploy again. It is either the name or the homepage that breaks

Comment: That didn't work. Thank you for your comment though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this once if this doesn't work.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: try to access wiith http://localhost:5000/client and remove " * " from app.use I have edited the answer.